# go-ethereum keccak256 multi value byte slice does not match solidity keccak256

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-debugging, golang

I have a smart contract with the following function:

```
function testHash(
    address _sender, 
    uint8 _method, 
    uint256 _number, 
    uint256 _amount) 
    public 
    returns (bytes32) 
{
return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_sender, _number, _method, _amount));    
}
```

Which when given the following values `0xa1d9e8788414eA9827f9639c4bd81bA8f3A29758, 0, 0, 0`  produces the following hash `0x65a0fc07391cb16f60c589836a72bdeaf2ab8bcb16c819126abba4408e069bcb`

I have the following golang code

```
func GenerateSignedPaymentMessage(ethAddress common.Address, paymentMethod uint8, paymentNumber, chargeAmountInWei *big.Int) []byte {
//keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, _paymentNumber, _paymentMethod, _chargeAmountInWei))

addressBytes := ethAddress.Bytes()
// we need to cast to []byte in order to generate a keccak hash
methodBytes := make([]byte, 1)
methodBytes[0] = byte(paymentMethod)
numberBytes := paymentNumber.Bytes()
amountBytes := chargeAmountInWei.Bytes()
// generate the hash
hash := crypto.Keccak256(addressBytes, numberBytes, methodBytes, amountBytes)
return hash
```

}

Which when I call like so

```
address := common.HexToAddress("0xa1d9e8788414eA9827f9639c4bd81bA8f3A29758")
method := uint8(0)
number := big.NewInt(0)
amount := big.NewInt(0)
hash := GenerateSignedPaymentMessage(address, method, number, amount)
fmt.Println(hash.String())
```

which gives the following output `0x7fc96d5f44e3e792633fcc981adf2bd0f644f0c167132eca5659b8a72d95bf07` which does not match the hash given by the solidity code. I'm unsure what to do here so any advice would be great!

EDIT:

As pointed out by smarx, I tried the following function

```
func TestHash(t *testing.T) {
address := common.HexToAddress("0xa1d9e8788414eA9827f9639c4bd81bA8f3A29758")
bn := make([]byte, 32)
ba := make([]byte, 32)
bm := make([]byte, 32)
bn[31] = 0
ba[31] = 0
bm[31] = 0
hash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(address.Bytes(), bn, ba, bm)
fmt.Println(hash.String())
}
```

Which produces the following hash `0xfc60222910c18ebcfd5610479223663effa903325f3db1db39a4d5fa37ba33a2`

Comment: What does `.Bytes()` do? My guess is it's not returning 32 bytes (the size of a `uint256`), because I don't see where you're providing information as to how many bytes to return.

Comment: Skimming the code of big.Int, I would say this is definitely the problem. You're probably only getting back a single byte for each. You'll need to figure out how to left pad the result to make it 32 bytes.

Comment: Ah okay that would make sense! I'll try and hopefully that fixes it :D

Answer (score 2):

It was definitely what smarx pointed out! I used the https://github.com/miguelmota/go-solidity-sha3 library, which works!

```
hash := payment.SoliditySHA3(
    payment.Address("0xa1d9e8788414eA9827f9639c4bd81bA8f3A29758"),
    payment.Uint8(big.NewInt(0)),
    payment.Uint256(big.NewInt(0)),
    payment.Uint256(big.NewInt(0)),
)
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hash))
```